# rm -rf recovery in Ubuntu using Terminal

Tags: 12.04

How can I recover files deleted in Ubuntu using `rm -f /pathtodirectory` with only having access to terminal? I tried `testdisk` but it did nothing and just quit.

Comment: Nope.  Once you `rm -rf`, it's gone.

Comment: `rm -rf` is basically "Get rid of this, I never ever want to see it again under any circumstances"

Comment: `testdisk` is for partition recovery.  `photorec` is for file recovery.  No guarantees that it would work, but you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have an alias somewhere `rm` (or `/bin/rm`) **completely** deletes a file from the disk. At that point the only way you *might* be able to recover is use data recovery software.